# wso2 convert json/xml to csv and write to a csv file

Tags: csv, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

i'm trying to create tab-delimited csv data from json/xml data. While I can do this using payload factory mediator in an iterate loop; the data gets appended to the same line in the file every iteration, creating a long line of data. I want to be append to the next line, but i've been unable to find a way. Any suggestions? Thanks.
(I do not want a solution which uses a csv connector or module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I solved it, you just need to use an xslt and "
" line break character.